# Phonegap: Resize webview on keyboard display in Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova, keyboard

I have a modal similar *(with fixed positioning)* to what facebook has for the comments in feed/chat in messenger in the latest android release. What I want looks similar to this:

[image]

So when you focus on the input the keyboard opens and shrinks the webview. It's not working by default and I can't find any solution.

I tried to add this preference to `config.xml` but `adjustResize` is not doing anything and `stateVisible` just opens the keyboard when I start the app.

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
```

Which is weird. As of the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) adjustResize should do this:

```
The activity's main window is always resized to 
make room for the soft keyboard on screen.
```

*I'm using Phonegap 3.0 and I have a Nexus 5 with kitkat for testing.*

Comment: I am not aware of how config.html gets pulled into the AndroidManifest.xml, but should android-windowSoftInputMode not be android:windowSoftInputMode? Have you tried altering the AndroidManifest.xml in the platforms/Android directory to have <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On my project created with phonegap 3.0, by default the app was full screen activity and the keyboard hid the app and the app was not resized.

I edited config.xml and set `<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />`, then the app was no more be full screen and when the soft keyboard was opened, the app was resized to fit the rest of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! it works. But i need to have my app on fullscreen mode. do you know another way around? i don't understand, shouldn't it by default (i assume adjustPan) locates the textbox and scroll so that the textbox is always visible?

Comment: Sorry, hadn't found other solution. Maybe you could change some settings directly in androidmanifest.xml.

Comment: Hey, I set this, I can see the STATUS BAR of device!! Also, UI will be disturbed !

Comment: I used this configuration to solve opposite problem: I have an app that, when the keybords rolls out, takes the @media styles for the tablet, since the webview resizes and becomes 'landscape' (on Nexus 4) - With this preference the webview remains fix and the form did not change anymore. Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on iOS. Any ideas for that?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution.. for specially "sencha/phonegap/cordova" users.

Edit the **Main activity in android manifest fil**e add this attribute.

**android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"**

```
 <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"  android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.company.appName.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter> 
</activity>
```