# Webview not resizing when keyboard appears

Tags: android, cordova, webview, android-softkeyboard

Need to resize my webview similar to Cordova/Phonegap when keyboard appears.
Right now as per below code, My input text fields are getting overlayed by device keyboard. I want to squeeze height of webview and make it adjust height above device keyboard.

**Activity code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_home">

<include android:id="@+id/head" layout="@layout/header" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/head"
    android:background="@drawable/overlay_bg2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="9dp" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLargeInverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest Entries :**

Theme   `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"`

Activity keyboard control `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Comment: Try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden` instead

Comment: No, it didn't worked.
I need to squeeze whole webview layout into area above keyboard

Comment: Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) and choose what you need @Abhinav Tyagi

Comment: It is not working. I have tried different combination of state and adjust.
How is Cordova doing it ???

Comment: This guy is using Cordova.... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21792412/4385913) I don't know if its what you want

Comment: Didn't help
I want to do like http://blog.vogella.com/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/
but this is also not working for webview

Comment: See what he [says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20511468/4385913)...

Comment: You can find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57623505/3819714

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, If your activity (or application as a whole) is set to full screen; **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"** won't work.

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: Make sure you are not using absolute position the css of in your webview.